# Laravel - Method in Model with Repository Paramater?

Tags: php, laravel, repository, view

I'm using laravel and i'm having some problems that I'm not quite sure what is the best way to do.

I have in my `views` Folder a file with the line:

```
{{ $user->permissionName() }}
```

The function `permissionName()` gets the User's `$permission_id` property and then it returns the name of the permission.

The problem is that I shouldn't get data from the model. I need to write this function on the `Repository` file. but now I have a new problem...
How do I get this function to the `view` file?

I rely on the fact that the data on mvc should be like:

```
Model > Repository > Controller > View
```

or am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couldn't you do this as a [relationship](http://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent#relationships) instead of writing a function? On your User model you could have a relationship like this:

```
/**
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOne
 */
public function permissionName()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\PermissionName', 'permission_id');
}
```

And then you could still use {{ $user->permissionName }} in your view.